# Count occurance of an element in PySpark DataFrame

Tags: csv, dataframe, pyspark, count

I have a csv file marks.csv. I have read it using pyspark and created a data frame df.

It looks like this (the csv file):

```
sub1,sub2,sub3
a,a,b
b,b,a
c,a,b
```

How can I get the count of ‘a’ in each column in the data frame df?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried something ? add your code if you did

Comment: As of now, I’ve tried df.count_values(a).

Comment: could you provide more information like what is your input dataframe and what is your expected output?

Comment: you can just count at your column `df.groupBy('sub1').count().show()
`

Comment: Hi @PIG, I want to count the occurrences of the value ‘a’ in each column. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can leverage SQL's features in Spark, we can simply do as below:

```
df.selectExpr("sum(if( sub1 = 'a' , 1, 0 )) as count1","sum(if( sub2 = 'a' , 1, 0 )) as count2","sum(if( sub3 = 'a' , 1, 0 )) as count3").show()
```

It should give output as below:

```
+------+------+------+
|count1|count2|count3|
+------+------+------+
|     1|     2|     1|
+------+------+------+
```

To know more about spark SQL please visit [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html).

**:EDIT:**

If you want to do it for all columns then you can try something like below:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import Row

    final_out = spark.createDataFrame([Row()]) # create an empty dataframe

    #Just loop through all columns

    for col_name in event_df.columns:
        final_out = final_out.crossJoin(event_df.selectExpr("sum(if( "+col_name+" = 'a' , 1, 0 )) as "+ col_name))

    final_out.show()
```

It should give you output like below:

```
    +----+----+----+
    |sub1|sub2|sub3|
    +----+----+----+
    |   1|   2|   1|
    +----+----+----+
```

Comment: Hi @Saurabh, is there any possible way of finding the count of all columns at once. Coz this method is more tedious for big csv files with 100s of columns. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE when statement to get count of "a" in each column

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F   

df2 = df.select( 
    F.sum(when(df("sub1")=="a",1).otherwise(0)).alias("sub1_cnt"),
    F.sum(when(df("sub2") == "a",1).otherwise(0)).alias("sub2_cnt"),
    F.sum(when(df("sub3") == "a",1).otherwise(0)).alias("sub3_cnt"))

df2.show()
```